# Javascript window.location is getting called again and again IE-8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, dom-events

I am  checking, getting and setting a cookie to trace the last visited page. And to do this I am calling a Javascript onload. Issue is when I execute this js, it refreshes again and again,  very much like a even on mouse movement. But I am not having any event other than onload.

Here is my js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

window.onload = function(event){        
    var currentPage = window.location.href;
    var lastVisited = getCookie('udis');
    var sessionId= getCookie('udisSession');
    if(lastVisited === null || lastVisited === undefined){
        setCookie("udis", currentPage, 365);
        lastVisited = getCookie('udis');
    }
    if(sessionId === null || sessionId === undefined){
        setSessionCookie('udisSession');
        if(lastVisited !== currentPage){
            window.location.href = lastVisited;         
        }           
    }
    setCookie("udis", currentPage, 365);
    updateBreadCrumb();
}

    function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
            x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
            x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            if (x==c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
    function setSessionCookie(c_name){
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + 'testSession'+';expires=;path=/';
}

    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";   expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }


//]]>
</script>
```

**This above code flawlessly in Firefox but in IE-8 it causing page to reload again and again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes your page to be reloaded.

```
window.location.href=lastVisited
```

You should probably check with an if statement to see if the current page is not the same and then refresh. Something like `window.location.href != lastVisited`